# The dialog box opens multiples time at a same time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-layout, box

whenever I click many times on wheel, open multiple dialog boxes at the same time.
I just want, it should be open after previous got dismissed.

[image]

I took an image and add animation on it and wrapped it with `GestureDetector` widget.
`onTap:` event i called `alertDialogBox()` method which is defined for Dialog box. watch above the gif image, and called the animation method with specific Condition

CODE:

**Dialog box**

```
alertDialogBox(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
       barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            content: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
             ....
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

**The Wheel:**

```
GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: _animationCtrl,
                        child:  Container(
                          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.3,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/wheel.png', ),
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(130.0)),
                          )
                        ),
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
                            .......
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  onTap: ()async{
                     await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documnet){
                      getIsSpin=documnet['isSpin'];


                    });

                    if(getIsSpin=="0"){
                         if (!_animationCtrl.isAnimating) {

                         //applying animation
                        }

                       DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                     // String lastSpinTime =DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(now);

                      .....//here updating isSpin value=1 and also updating   spining Date time to firestore

                   }else {
                     oneDayDuration();
                   }


                  }

                )
```

After 24 hours trying to spin the wheel

**oneDayDuration():**

```
void oneDayDuration()async{
int differenceTime;

await({
   ....here fetching last spin date time from firestore});
   ....//here getting difference hours between last spining time and current time

    if(differenceTime>=24){

         await({......//updating ispin=0 to firbase
        })    
        .then((result)  => {


          print("Now you're able to spin"),

        }).catchError((err) => print(err)); 
    }else{
      print("Please wait for 24 hours");

      alertDialogBox(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can somone help without seeing the code .?

Comment: How we are supposed to solve the problem without looking at the code?

Comment: Now, you can see, I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is because, you are trying to show dialog **Asynchronously**, where you don't have to. Just remove `async`, it is unnecessary while showing a simple dialog.

You better create a method that runs async in the `if condition`, and remove async in the `onTap`. This will separate your dialog code with `async`.

Comment: You are right but I'm using Cloud Firestore, that's why I need  `async`. and I'm not showing simply.

Comment: You are using Firestore queries inside dialog, are you?

Comment: no no, I'm using Cloud firestore queries inside the `onTap:` event with a condition means  `if(){...}else{alertDialogBobx();}`. Please recheck my updated code.

Comment: Still same issue. Wait show you my whole code, what exactly I'm doing.

Comment: Please recheck again, I have updated my code  `onTap:`.

Answer (score 1):

It is too late to answer this question, I came across the same scenario and solved it.

This is because the alertDialogBox function is invoked by build method every time the state is changed. you need to limit it by adding a variable to class like 'isAlertboxOpened' and make opening of alertDialogBox conditional and avoid opening multiple dialog boxes.

The following code should work

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  bool isAlertboxOpened; // add this

@override
void initState(){
  isAlertboxOpened = false; // add this
}

alertDialogBox(BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() => isAlertboxOpened = true); // add this
    return showDialog(
       barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            content: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
             ....
            // when press ok button on pressed add this
             onPressed:(){
                 // your code
                 setState(() => isAlertboxOpened = false);
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }

          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

void oneDayDuration()async{
int differenceTime;

await({
   ....here fetching last spin date time from firestore});
   ....//here getting difference hours between last spining time and current time

    if(differenceTime>=24){

         await({......//updating ispin=0 to firbase
        })    
        .then((result)  => {


          print("Now you're able to spin"),

        }).catchError((err) => print(err)); 
    }else{
      print("Please wait for 24 hours");
      isAlertboxOpened ? (){} : // add this to make this conditional 
      alertDialogBox(context);
    }
  }
}
```